# New in Python Vectors Need Advice

Tags: python

I have an exam in two days and we an example from teacher, but I'm new to Python, and I kind of blocked at this

This is the problem statement:

> Write an algorithm which will get the parameters two array of integers x[1..n] if y[1..n] which returns number of common elements in the two arrays.

```
def apartine(a,e):
    e=1
    gasit=False
    n=len(a)
    i=0
    while i<=n and gasit==False:
        if a[i]==e:
            gasit=True
        else:
            i=i+1
    return gasit

def intersectie(a,b,c):
    e=0
    k=len(c)
    m=len(b)
    for i in range(1,m):
        if apartine(a,e)==True:
            k=k+1
            c.append(b[i])
            print(c)
    return c

a=[1,3,5,7]
b=[2,3,4,6]
c=[]
print intersectie(a,b,c)
```

I'm stuck with this.

I need some help to find out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: That's a poorly-written problem statement. I suspect that your teacher means "list" rather than "array". (They're not the same thing!)

Comment: Also, Python lists are 0-based so it's strange that your teacher wrote `x[1..n]`.

Comment: Hmm; maybe the problem statement isn't supposed to be specific to Python?

Comment: Please explain the question properly. Also, the code is unreadable too. Please write comments to explain it (What is `c`, `apartine`, `gasit` etc. ?)

Comment: apartine = belongs, gasit = found

Answer (score 3):

A simple list comprehension can do that :

```
c=[i for i in a if i in b]
```

Comment: That is O(N^2), so it won't scale very well.

Comment: True, but this was not an issue here :)

Answer (score 0):

One issue you have in `apartine()` is that `a[len(a)]` (`a[i]` in the last run through the `while` loop) will raise an exception. Valid indices are from `0` to `len(a)-1`.

`e=1` means `apartine()` will only look to see if `1` is in `a`, rather than whatever was passed.

You want to call `apartine(a, b[i])`, `e` doesn't seem to have any meaningful value.

You're not using `k`.

A very simple way to implement the whole thing in Python would be:

```
c = list(set(a) & set(b))
```

but I assume that's not what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If the position in the lists doesn't matter you can get the common elements with a simple comprehension list

```
commons = [x for x in a if x in b]
```

If the position matters, you could use the index

```
commons = [a[i] for i in range(len(a)) if a[i] == b[i]]
```

The number of elements in common would be the length of this list

```
print(len(commmons))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're having difficulty following the list comprehensions, here's basically the same thing written as a for loop:

```
def intersect(a, b):
    """Return a list of all elements common to a & b
    """
    intersection = []
    for element in a:
        if element in b and element not in intersection:
            intersection.append(element)
    return intersection


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_pairs = (
        ([1, 3, 5, 7], [2, 3, 4, 6]),
        ([3], [1, 2, 3]),
        ([1, 2, 3], [3]),
        ([3, 3, 3], [3]),
        ([3], [3, 3, 3]),
        ([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
    )
    for a, b in test_pairs:
        print "Intersection of %s and %s is %s" % (a, b, intersect(a,b))
```

The output is:

```
Intersection of [1, 3, 5, 7] and [2, 3, 4, 6] is [3]
Intersection of [3] and [1, 2, 3] is [3]
Intersection of [1, 2, 3] and [3] is [3]
Intersection of [3, 3, 3] and [3] is [3]
Intersection of [3] and [3, 3, 3] is [3]
Intersection of [1, 2, 3] and [4, 5, 6] is []
```

The methodology is to take each element from one list (it doesn't matter which one) and see if it exists in the other list.  Collect these elements in a third list which is your result.   As you can see, this duplicates are removed by the `element not in intersection` clause.